# is MailHog mail application secure?

Tags: security

I have a task to setup a MailHog script on our VPS but also they asked me about security about this script, but i don't have an experience about security stuff.

this is the script github account: https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog

also i have checked their security page on github.com but there is no security issues: https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog/security/advisories

Comment: Why not consult an actual security expert…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after i pentesting the script i have found two vulnerabilities

1. SMTP injection
2. Memory Leak leads to Denial for service .

these vulnerabilities occur due to defaults settings .

Comment: could you talk more about the details? especially the 2nd. thanks a lot~

Comment: It's a developer tool for local development, and should never be used as a real SMTP service.